# Error al recorrer XML con PHP

Tags: php, xml

Presento problemas al recorrer un XML con PHP.

Este es mi archivo XML

```
<root>
    <continentes>
        <continente name="Asia">...</continente>
        <continente name="Europa">...</continente>
        <continente name="África">...</continente>
        <continente name="América">
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>...</item>
            <item>
                <country>Colombia</country>
                <cases>8613</cases>
                <todayCases>0</todayCases>
                <deaths>378</deaths>
                <todayDeaths>0</todayDeaths>
                <recovered>2013</recovered>
                <active>6222</active>
                <critical>128</critical>
                <tests>127105</tests>
                <channel>colombia</channel>
                <countryInfo>...</countryInfo>
            </item>
        </continente>
        <continente name="Oceanía">...</continente>
        <continente name="Otros">...</continente>
    </continentes>
</root>
```

Me interese unicamente la información de Colombia, pero al momento de recorrer el XML para llegar allá, solo me muestra el primer `continente`.

De esta manera lo estoy recorriendo:

```
$archivoXML = simplexml_load_file("/informacioncovid19.xml");

foreach ( $archivoXML->continentes as $XML ) {
    echo $XML->continente["name"];
}
```

Y como resultado solo obtengo: `Asia` que es el primer continente del XML.

Comment: `var_dump($archivoXML->continentes);` muestra `continente` como arreglo, entonces debes recorrer `$archivoXML->continentes->continente` y mostrar el nombre con `$XML['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al aporte de Triby, para obtener solo los datos de Colombia, realice lo siguiente:

```
$archivoXML = simplexml_load_file("/informacioncovid19.xml");

foreach ( $archivoXML->continentes->continente as $continente ) {
    if ( $continente["name"] == "América" ) {
        foreach ( $continente->item as $pais ) {
            if ( $pais->country == "Colombia" ) {
                #code...
            }
        }
    }
}
```